# PHP form after submission should show reminder message every 30mins after reminder time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a form field's time interval, reminder time, reminder message. If current time exceeds reminder time it should should show reminder message as alert in particular time interval. Suggest me best solution.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: Showing what you already tried would be appreciated too :)

Comment: i know it can be done by lots of methods, but it will be helpful if you can suggest me best logic. thank you :)

Comment: You really need to show some efforts, because we are not a code-service where we coding for you, i'm sorry to say that.

Comment: I agree with @C0dekid: show what you have tried. If you haven't tried anything, try something and ask later.

Comment: ok fine,let me try my logic and if it's not working will ping again.
thank you :)